# My AC-DC PFC rectifier self-boosts voltage when with no load

Tags: ac-dc, power-factor-correction

I have made a PFC IC [LT1249](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1249fbs.pdf) reference design - a few differences are 820 uH inductor, 1.1 mF capacitor and different MOSFET.

When I connect AC (50 V) with no control (17 V) voltage the DC output rises and in ~10s reaches 170 V. Putting a 100 Ω load results in low <50 V DC voltage. Turning on the IC (via 17 V) results in no output change.

I have already tried UC2852 PFC IC, which also resulted in very similar problem - sharp output rise with no load and not operating at all with load when fully on.

Both designs were on self-made PCB. On current (LT1249) I also put lead on every copper track to make sure proper connection.

My overall goal is working ~100 W PFC rectifier.

Has anyone had experience with PFC ICs? Do they have some delicate secrets about their usage?

Thank you.

Comment: A schematic is needed.

Comment: Is this meant for line voltage use? On that case it’s target is in the ballpark of 400VDC, and there must be a load for voltage regulation to work. You have not provided any details of what you actually did. And doing this on a breadboard requires quite a bit of care. Breadboards are designed for use up to 48VAC. And they have bad parasitics so controlling switching elements requires more care than on a well laid out PCB. I’d say doing this on a breadboard is going at it in hard mode compared to getting a bunch of PCBs made.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

A few issues with the reference design:

[image]

The resistor divider (1M and 20K) set the output voltage.  It must divide the output voltage down to 7.5 volts, so that this combination would have an operating point of 350 volts or so.

[image]

Pin IAC is biased to 2 volts, so with about 50 volts as your input, the current into IAC is 50 volts / 1Mohm or 50uA.  Not much input into the current amplifier:

[image]

Finally, the current amplifier can only increase the current at the output.  If you have no load except the output capacitor, there is nothing in this circuit that can reduce the output voltage (drive it negative), so running unloaded will always cause an overvoltage situation.  These devices have relatively slow loop response, so be aware that a rapid decrease in load will also cause overvoltage transients.

However, if you have faithfully selected the parts in the reference design and used good assembly practices, this circuit should provide about 380 volts with an input of 120 or 240VAC.  Your output capacitance must be rated for this voltage, along with your MOSFET - I would be really conservative with the MOSFET rating for a breadboard.  Be aware that this circuit will generate a dangerous (potentially lethal) level of voltage and current, and, even fused as shown, presents a real shock hazard.  The circuit would not support a theoretical 100-ohm load (for very long!) as this would be 380 volts/3.8 amps/1444 watts.

Good luck!

Comment: I'm going to be nerdy and pedantic and expand on this statement: _even fused as shown, presents a real shock hazard_ -- because fuses don't protect _you_ from shock.  They protect the circuit from shorts, which might, in turn, cause a fire.  @JohnBirkhead already knows this, but it bears repeating, IMHO.

Comment: You are correct sir.

Comment: Hi, yes I tested it at lower, safer voltage of ~50V. So resistor was 330k instead of 1Meg to give ~130V of DC. The biggest problem was that when IC wasn't powered (so it was simple diode bridge) the DC output voltage constantly was climbing. I guess it could have been because of 820uH inductor?

Comment: Power factor correction is accomplished by controlling the rate of charge of the inductor and then injecting its energy as DC current into a load.  Without a DC load, the circuit has no way to regulate; injecting a current into a capacitor will increase its voltage, and without a resistive load, there is no mechanism to reduce the voltage.   So this type of design relies on having a DC load to operate.

Comment: Not sure about this part when it is "off" but you can certainly simulate a bridge, inductor and capacitor in a SPICE program.